# Не удаётся получить дату из DatePicker

Tags: java, android, datepicker

Создал в своём приложении `AlertDialog` с `DatePicker` с использованием `DialogFragment`. Затем, чтобы иметь возможность использовать `DialogFragment` вместе с активностями, перенёс создание `View` для диалога в метод `DialogFragment.onCreateView(...)`, однако после этого перестал работать код, получающий дату, точнее, теперь он всегда возвращает дату, которая была установлена вызовом `mDatePicker.init(...)`.

Первый вариант:

**DatePickerFragment**

```java
...

public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    ...

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Date date = (Date)getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_DATE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_date, null);

        mDatePicker = (DatePicker)v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_date_picker);
        mDatePicker.init(year, month, day, null);

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setView(v)
                .setTitle(R.string.date_picker_title)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // этот код возвращает правильную дату
                                int year = mDatePicker.getYear();
                                int month = mDatePicker.getMonth();
                                int day = mDatePicker.getDayOfMonth();
                                Date date = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day).getTime();
                                sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, date);
                            }
                        })
                .create();
    }
}
```

**dialog_date.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DatePicker
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_date_picker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:calendarViewShown="false" />
```

Второй вариант:

**DatePickerFragment**

```java
...

public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    ...

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Date date = (Date)getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_DATE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_picker_layout, null);

        mDatePicker = (DatePicker)v.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
        mDatePicker.init(year, month, day, null);

        Button okButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.ok_date_picker_button);
        okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // этот код возвращает неправильную дату
                int year = mDatePicker.getYear();
                int month = mDatePicker.getMonth();
                int day = mDatePicker.getDayOfMonth();
                Date date = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day).getTime();
                System.out.println(date);
                sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, date);
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(DatePickerFragment.this).commit();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setView(onCreateView(LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()), null, null))
                .create();
    }
}
```

**date_picker_layout.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_picker_title_textview"
        android:text="@string/date_picker_title"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/date_picker"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/date_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/date_picker_title_textview"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/ok_date_picker_button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ok_date_picker_button"
        android:text="@string/ok_date_picker_button_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/date_picker"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Я подозреваю что в таком случае у вас в режиме диалога `onCreateView` вызывается дважды. Гайд говорит: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs?hl=ru#FullscreenDialog, что в таком случае не следует билдить диалог, а оставить это на совесть API.

Comment: @woesss действительно так, спасибо. Не смог найти информации сам по этому поводу, к сожалению.